# Azure Web Api Resource Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webapi

I have a web API application that I have deployed in a virtual machine running windows server 2012 SQL edition.

I am trying to move it off of the VM into Azure web sites.

I can debug the application on my local development computer having it attach to the new SQL storage and that all works fine.

I also can still run it on the VM it is currently in.

When I deploy to Azure web sites, however, when I try to do a web API call I get:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have tried debugging the site, but it never hits any of the entry points that I can think to put break point in.

Can someone please help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: what is the connection string you are using (leave out your password)